# Foreign key in two models on Rails 3 from code school sample

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I just can not why the two model both set the foreign id => tweeter_id

In my thought, the foreign key is to point to one model's primary key

For example there are model A and B

the model B wants to refer to model A.

But the default primary key of model A maybe has changed to aaa_id  not being a_id anymore.

So the model B has to set aaa_id as it's foreign key in order to refer to model A?

I can't understand why we should add foreign key on model Tweet,

And the model Tweet doesn't have the column tweeter_id.

The question's description

```
FOREIGN KEY
Objective
OH NO! Our Database Admin turned into a Zombie and decided to rename the belongs_to 
field in our locations table tweeter_id instead of the intelligent default tweet_id. 
We're going to slay him and correct this, but in the meantime set the foreign_key on 
both relationships to tweeter_id. 
Also set the dependency so when a tweet is destroyed, 
the location is destroyed as well.
```

=end

The model file

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :location ,dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :tweeter_id
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tweet, class_name: "Tweet" , foreign_key: :tweeter_id
end
```

The scheme

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110814152905) do

  create_table "locations" do |t| 
    t.integer "name"
    t.integer "tweeter_id" # BRAINS!!!
  end

  create_table "tweets" do |t|
    t.string "message"
    t.boolean "show_location", :default => false
    t.integer "zombie_id"

    t.timestamps
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the `belongs_to :tweet` in `class Location` has already been defined prior. Since it has been changed, you must create a new reference to link the two.

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, foreign_key: :tweeter_id, dependent: :destroy
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tweet, foreign_key: :tweeter_id  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of `has_one` and `belong_to` being two sides of the same relation.

The `Location` refers to the `Tweet` -- it has the foreign key, `tweeter_id`.

The `Tweet` on the other hand, does not refer to the location -- it doesn't have a `location_id`.

So, there is one relation here: `Tweet <-> Location`. There is only one foreign key -- remember that a foreign key is a key in one table that is a reference to a key in another table.

Both the `has_one` and the `belong_to` associations refer to this one relation, just existing on different sides of it. Since they both refer to this location, they both use the `tweeter_id` as the foreign key.